# Using MyNav Python Scripts With IDA Pro 6.1 On Windows 7

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I just came across the MyNav Python scripts and would like to use some of their functionality on my IDA Pro database. I have IdaPython installed properly, but I cannot seem to get the plugins to show up in the menu. I have gone to File > script and run MyNav.py, but all that happens is the myexport.pyc and mybrowser.pyc files get generated where I have the source files.

I tried copying those into the plugins directory and restarting, but nothing shows up. The install documentation on the google code page is non-existent. Has anyone had any success installing this plugin package?

I am using Python 2.7 with IdaPython 1.5.2, but have also tried with Python 2.6

Comment: _"I cannot seem to get the plugins to show up in the menu"_ - Where in the menu are you looking? After you run `mynav.py`, the new menu items should appear in the **Edit → Plugins** menu.

Comment: That is where I looked an I only see the following items, Sample plugin, Jump to next fixup, and Sample chart builder.

Comment: That's weird. Menu-items should be populated. Can you run, for example, the script mybrowser.py to see if the browser appears? PS: I'm the author.

Comment: I ran it and saw a graph pop up with boxes and a bunch of blue lines connecting them. I think it is the right output I should be seeing.,

Comment: @joxeankoret I don't know if it helps any, but also tried running the myexport.py and it get an error "Unable to open database file...\python\idaapi.py in IDAPython_ExecScript" There is more, but it's just a stack unwind from what it looks like. Line 80 in openDatabase, 280 in main, and 284 in <module> main(). I can post a screenshot in my question if you need it.